# Jekyll architect theme not working on GitHub page

Tags: github, jekyll

I created a GitHub page with a repository called myusername.github.io
I cloned that (empty) repo to my PC and using jekyll command line I created a new blog inside of this folder. It was building correctly on my PC and on GitHub with the standard theme 'minima'.
However, I wanted to use the 'architect' theme and followed their instructions (just add `theme: jekyll-theme-architect` on the _config.yml) to use it but got a messed up page as a result. What is going on? How can I fix that?

I am totally pissed off by this. The instruction is so simple, but does not work!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to not having the proper gem locally, so you can install the gem explicitely or add the `github-pages` gem that contains that theme as it is supported by Github pages.

Add the following to your site's `Gemfile`:

```
gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins
```

then run `bundle install`.

Edit `index.md` and change the layout to the default one: `layout: default`.

Remove the lines that contains an include tag in `about.md` for example: `{% include icon-github.html username="jekyll" %}`.

and you will be able to use the new theme.

Comment: Just tried that now... I had to run bundle update 'cause of some conflicts before. It is still not working...

Comment: I got no error while using jekyll. However I received a lot of e-mails from GitHub, all of them with the same message:
"A file was included in `about.md` that is a symlink or does not exist in your `_includes` directory. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-file-is-a-symlink/."

Comment: So you were able to run Jekyll locally with the new theme?

Comment: I don't know if I was clear. First I tried your suggestion, then there were conflict error messages that told me to run `bundle update` and then trying again, which I did and it worked. However when I used `git push -u origin master` and tried to visualize the page on the browser using myusername.github.io, the page was messed up again. During this last process I got no errors but the ones that were emailed to me.

Comment: When I ran `bundle exec jekyll serve` I got this error: `Configuration file: /home/luis/Documentos/trabalho/programmed_biology/site/programmedbio.github.io/_config.yml
Configuration file: /home/luis/Documentos/trabalho/programmed_biology/site/programmedbio.github.io/_config.yml
jekyll 3.4.3 | Error:  Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.`

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: don't forget to sudo !

Comment: @Gildas sudo or use a custom path where your user has privileges with bundle install --path

Comment: This is a great answer. I'm so frustrated GitHub help doesn't make any mention of this. I've tried to setup Jekyll about a half dozen times before and the GitHub Pages and Jekyll setups don't work well together. Thanks to your answer I see the information I needed was in the Gemfile comments. But as a new user to Jekyll this isn't where I"m going to look first. Rather I'm going to click the "Change Theme" button on GitHub Settings and just find that it never works.

Comment: @MichaelWelch I'm glad it was helpful, Jekyll evolves fast so there are some gaps in procedures with all the themes thing and github pages service.